# I removed libisimulate but i get a warning if i compile. What's wrong?

Tags: iphone, xcode, installation, ld

so I installed this: http://www.vimov.com/isimulate/ then i removed it because i didn't need it anymore. But now I get this warning every time I compile:

> ld: warning: directory '/Users//../../Downloads/libisimulate-4.x-1.5-20100925-opengl' following -L not found

I deleted all. I searched for anything which contains "isim" with the finder and i did not find anything. What's wrong?

**EDIT: And it says something with `Project <App name> Configuration Debug`**

Comment: What build environment/tools?   I assume from your handle this is for Mac/Iphone?   My guess is that your Makefile has your library directory added to it, which is being passed to ld.  Ld is just complaining that the directory no longer exists.

Comment: I'm using Xcode and developing for the iPhone. How can I remove this warning? Because it's annoying me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> XCode ld: warning: directory ..
>   following -F not found To resolve this
>   warning in XCode, browse the App
>   Target Preference and look for library
>   paths. Make sure you remove ant
>   invalid search paths, rebuild. Warning
>   should disappear.
>
> ld: warning: directory '/some path'
>   following -F not found

This worked.